# Cloudformation error for vgw not found, times out

Tags: aws-cloudformation

The following is a template that creates a VPC VPN connection but it keeps timing out trying to find the VGW. Can someone help modify it or point the mistake?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: aws vpc-vpn connection for AGERO by ekumar
Outputs:
  PrivateSubnet:
    Description: SubnetId of the VPN connected subnet
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet
  VPCId:
    Description: VPCId of the newly created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
Parameters:
  OnPremiseCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24
    Description: IP Address range for your existing infrastructure
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  SubnetCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.1.0.0/24
    Description: IP Address range for the VPN connected Subnet
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  VPCCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.1.0.0/16
    Description: IP Address range for the VPN connected VPC
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  VPNAddress:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP address of the form x.x.x.x
    Default: 98.216.131.178
    Description: IP Address of your VPN device
    MaxLength: '15'
    MinLength: '7'
    Type: String
Resources:
  CustomerGateway:
    Properties:
      BgpAsn: '65000'
      IpAddress: !Ref VPNAddress
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: VPN
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - 'Gateway to '
              - !Ref VPNAddress
      Type: ipsec.1
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway'
  InboundPrivateNetworkAclEntry:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      Egress: 'false'
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      RuleNumber: '100'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
  OutBoundPrivateNetworkAclEntry:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      Egress: 'true'
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      RuleNumber: '100'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
  PrivateNetworkAcl:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
  PrivateRoute:
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn: VPNGateway
  PrivateRouteTable:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected Subnet
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
  PrivateSubnet:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref SubnetCIDR
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected Subnet
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
  PrivateSubnetNetworkAclAssociation:
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
  VPC:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPCCIDR
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC' 
    DependsOn: VPNConnection
  VPNConnection:
    Properties:
      CustomerGatewayId: !Ref CustomerGateway
      StaticRoutesOnly: 'true'
      Type: ipsec.1
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNConnection'
  VPNConnectionRoute:
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref OnPremiseCIDR
      VpnConnectionId: !Ref VPNConnection
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute'  
  VPNGateway:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      Type: ipsec.1
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNGateway'
  VPNGatewayAttachment:
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
```

The error returned is:

```
**20:23:22 UTC-0400 CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Route PrivateRoute    The gateway ID 'vgw-a359aeca' does not exist**
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the vgw is never getting associated with your VPC, hence any association in route table for the same would fail as the vgw is not at all present in your VPC.

Following is a slight modification on the template to wait on for completion of vgwattachment, and then do other tasks.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: aws vpc-vpn connection for XYZ by ekumar
Outputs:
  PrivateSubnet:
    Description: SubnetId of the VPN connected subnet
    Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet
  VPCId:
    Description: VPCId of the newly created VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
Parameters:
  OnPremiseCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.0.0.0/24
    Description: IP Address range for your existing infrastructure
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  SubnetCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.1.0.0/24
    Description: IP Address range for the VPN connected Subnet
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  VPCCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
    Default: 10.1.0.0/16
    Description: IP Address range for the VPN connected VPC
    MaxLength: '18'
    MinLength: '9'
    Type: String
  VPNAddress:
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP address of the form x.x.x.x
    Default: 98.216.131.178
    Description: IP Address of your VPN device
    MaxLength: '15'
    MinLength: '7'
    Type: String
Resources:
  VPC:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPCCIDR
      EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
      EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'  
    DependsOn: VPNConnection
  CustomerGateway:
    Properties:
      BgpAsn: '65000'
      IpAddress: !Ref VPNAddress
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: VPN
          Value: !Join 
            - ''
            - - 'Gateway to '
              - !Ref VPNAddress
      Type: ipsec.1
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway'
  PrivateNetworkAcl:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
  InboundPrivateNetworkAclEntry:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      Egress: 'false'
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      RuleNumber: '100'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
  OutBoundPrivateNetworkAclEntry:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      Egress: 'true'
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      PortRange:
        From: '0'
        To: '65535'
      Protocol: '6'
      RuleAction: allow
      RuleNumber: '100'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
  VPNConnection:
    Properties:
      CustomerGatewayId: !Ref CustomerGateway
      StaticRoutesOnly: 'true'
      Type: ipsec.1
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNConnection'
  VPNConnectionRoute:
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: !Ref OnPremiseCIDR
      VpnConnectionId: !Ref VPNConnection
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute'  
  VPNGateway:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      Type: ipsec.1
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPNGateway'
  VPNGatewayAttachment:
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      VpnGatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
  PrivateRoute:
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref VPNGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    DependsOn: VPNGateway
  PrivateRouteTable:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected Subnet
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    DependsOn: VPNGatewayAttachment
  PrivateSubnet:
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref SubnetCIDR
      Tags:
        - Key: Application
          Value: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
        - Key: Network
          Value: VPN Connected Subnet
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
  PrivateSubnetNetworkAclAssociation:
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId: !Ref PrivateNetworkAcl
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
```

Also for readibility please keep Outputs section at the end. And do keep a note of the order in which the resources need to be created.

P.S. :Do not put the Company Name in question :)